# How to automate powering of a USB port?

Tags: usb, power, usb-power-delivery

### The Problem

I have a bonkers KVM switch configuration to control 4 monitors across 2 PCs and a raspberry pi, and due to the nature of my configuration one of my monitors occasionally needs to have a video repeater power cycled for the signal to be displayed. I'd like to apply more automation to this.

I've primarily encountered this issue with my work PC (I'm guessing because I mostly use my work PC these days OR "fixing" the issue on my work PC might alleviate issues I would have encountered on my personal PC on that particular day). So possible solutions would need to work in an environment where I have more limited access within Windows.

### Options I've considered

#### "USB vacuum switch"

Is there such a thing as a [vacuum switch](https://www.amazon.com/Vacuum-Switch/s?k=Vacuum%20Switch), but for USB? A vacuum switch plugs into a wall outlet and has two output outlets. When power is sensed in one of the output outlets, then the other output becomes powered (for example, automatically turning on a vacuum to collect dust when a saw is turned on). I figure if such a device exists I could find a way to leverage it and solve my problem. Otherwise using an actual vacuum switch might work for my application. Any thoughts?

#### Toggling enabled state of USB hub providing power

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1438371/win32-api-function-to-programmatically-enable-disable-device/73053963#73053963) (didn't work or I didn't have high enough access). This seems to be a common question that doesn't have a solid answer without admin access.

Comment: You have already put in more energy than simply replacing the KVM switch. USB ports are not made to cover broken KVM switches.

Comment: Get a smart plug and plug your USB charger into it.